# How is IEnumerable<T> Contra-variant?

Tags: c#, generics, ienumerable, covariance, contravariance

This post ([http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2005/01/18/355755.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20140417104304/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2005/01/18/355755.aspx)) says `IEnumerable<T>` is Contra-variant. However type T is co-variant because it is an `out` parameter. So in what context is `IEnumerable<T>` Contra-variant ??

Hope I am not confusing! Thanks for the answers in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IEnumerable isn't contra-variant. It's covariant.

From MSDN [(IEnumerable<(Of <(T>)>)  Interface)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1?view=net-5.0)  we have that:

> Type Parameters
>
> out T
>
> The type of objects to enumerate.
> **This type parameter is covariant**. That is, you can use either the type
> you specified or any type that is more
> derived.

From this [post](http://blog.voidnish.com/?p=188) we have that:

> The Base Class Library has been updated to support covariance and
> contravariance in various commonly
> used interfaces. For example,
> IEnumerable  is now **a covariant
> interface** – IEnumerable.

Sample code:

```
// Covariant parameters can be used as result types
interface IEnumerator<out T>
{
     T Current { get; }

     bool MoveNext();
}

// Covariant parameters can be used in covariant result types 
interface IEnumerable<out T>
{
     IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator();
}

// Contravariant parameters can be used as argument types 
interface IComparer<in T>
{
     bool Compare(T x, T y); 
}
```

For more examples on this, take a look at:

[Covariance and Contravariance FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/csharpfaq/covariance-and-contravariance-faq)

[Covariance and Contravariance in C#, Part One](https://web.archive.org/web/20151107135457/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/16/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-one.aspx) (Great series of posts by Eric Lippert about Covariance And Contravariance)

[Understanding C# Covariance And Contravariance (3) Samples](https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/understanding-csharp-covariance-and-contravariance-3-samples)

Comment: More to the point: the blog entry referenced in the question is incorrect. The writer confused co- and contra-variance. Which is easy to do, IMO...

Comment: Exactly. Brad contradicts himself in the post.

Comment: That is what I thought. However, since the blog post mentioned it came from Anders -- the C# Architect and Guru, I was doubtful ! Thanks for clarifying it.