# Why generic IList<> does not inherit non-generic IList

Tags: c#, .net, generics, library-design

`IList<T>` does not inherit `IList` where `IEnumerable<out T>` inherits `IEnumerable`.

If `out` modifier are the only reason then why most of the implementation of `IList<T>` (e.g. `Collection<T>`, `List<T>`) implements `IList` interface.

So any one can say OK, if that statements is true for all implementation of `IList<T>` then directly cast it to `IList` when necessary. But problem is that though `IList<T>` does not inherit `IList` so it is not guaranteed that every `IList<T>` object are `IList`.

Moreover using `IList<object>` is obviously not the solution because without `out` modifier generics can not be assigned to a less inherit class; and creating new instance of List is not a solution here because someone may want actual reference of the `IList<T>` as an `IList` pointer; and use `List<T>` insteed of `IList<T>` is actually a bad programming practice and doesn't serve all purpose.

If .NET wants to give flexibility that every implementation of `IList<T>` should not have a contract of non-generic implementation (i.e. `IList`) then why they didn't keep another interface which implement both generic and non-generic version and didn't suggest that all concrete class which want to contract for generic and non-genetic item should contract via that interface.

Same problem occurs for casting `ICollection<T>` to `ICollection` and `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` to `IDictionary`.

Comment: See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2005/01/18/355755.aspx

Comment: @JonSkeet I think he has an error in the article. Ienumerable is Covariant and not Contravariant. . search for this exact phrase in the article :  _"As it turns out, the only generic interface for which this is possible is IEnumerable<T>, because only IEnumerable<T> is contra-variant:"_

Comment: Do not worry about your difficulties in Mathematics. I can assure you mine are still greater. _Albert Einstein_, for your guide `:D`

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Yes, I think you're right - but the rest of the article is still appropriate.

Comment: @Nafeez Abrar: what's you actual problem you need to solve?

Comment: @CodesInChaos: so tell me how you would call the "Add" method when you don't know the generic type at compile time, without using the "legacy interface"?

Comment: @StefanSteinegger If I wanted to forgo the safety of static typing, then I'd go with `dynamic` or reflection. But that's pretty rare in my experience.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: reflection gets really nasty when dealing with generics. Just to call "Add" on a collection it is overkill. But you are right, its a very rare case. Anyway I enjoy having a nice interface independent of how much type information I have at compile time. The problem is not that non-generic is obsolete, the problem is that Microsoft didn't manage to create useful and consistent collection interfaces.

Comment: @JonSkeet the link is now broken, as many other great blog posts in MSDN, as I found recently. Any chance they've been moved elsewhere known?
Anyway, for this one specifically I found a copy in the Wayback Machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20140417104304/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2005/01/18/355755.aspx

Comment: @alelom: I don't know of anywhere, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you note, `T` in `IList<T>` is not *covariant*. As a rule of thumb: any class that can modify its state cannot be covariant. The reason is that such classes often have methods that have `T` as the type of one of their parameters, e.g. `void Add(T element)`. And covariant type parameters are not allowed in *input* positions.

Generics were added, among other reasons, to provide type safety. For example, you can't add an `Elephant` to a list of `Apple`. If `ICollection<T>` were to extend `ICollection`, then you could call `((ICollection)myApples).Add(someElephant)` without a compile-time error, as `ICollection` has a method `void Add(object obj)`, which seemingly allows you to add *any* object to the list, while in practice you can only add objects of `T`. Therefore, `ICollection<T>` does not extend `ICollection` and `IList<T>` does not extend `IList`.

Anders Hejlsberg, one of the creators of C#, [explains it like this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2005/01/18/355755.aspx):

> Ideally all of the generic collection interfaces (e.g. `ICollection<T>`, `IList<T>`) would inherit from their non-generic counterparts such that generic interface instances could be used both with generic and non-generic code.
>
> As it turns out, the only generic interface for which this is possible is `IEnumerable<T>`, because only `IEnumerable<T>` is contra-variant *[sic<sup>1</sup>]*: In `IEnumerable<T>`, the type parameter `T` is used only in "output" positions (return values) and not in "input" positions (parameters). `ICollection<T>` and `IList<T>` use `T` in both input and output positions, and those interfaces are therefore invariant.

<sup>1</sup>) `IEnumerable<T>` is *co*-variant

---

Since .Net 4.5 there are the [`IReadOnlyCollection<out T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh881542.aspx) and [`IReadOnlyList<out T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh192385.aspx) covariant interfaces. But `IList<T>`, `ICollection<T>` and many of the list and collection classes don't implement or extend them. Frankly, I find them not very useful, as they only define `Count` and `this[int index]`.

---

If I could redesign .Net 4.5 from the ground up, I would have split the list interface into a read-only covariant interface `IList<out T>` that includes `Contains` and `IndexOf`, and a mutable invariant interface `IMutableList<T>`. Then you could cast `IList<Apple>` to `IList<object>`. I implemented this here:

> [**M42 Collections**](https://bitbucket.org/Virtlink/m42-collections/) - Covariant collections, lists and arrays.

Comment: Any implementation of `IList<T>` could legitimately implement `IList` by saying having `IList.IsReadOnly` return `true` even if `IList<T>.IsReadOnly` is false.  Note that `String[]` implements both `IList<String>` and `IList<Object>`; the `IsReadOnly` property of the former will return false, but the `IsReadOnly` property of the latter will return true, so the idea of a collection which implements several "maybe-writable" interfaces and is writable by some but not all is hardly unknown.

Comment: Your answer is correct, but the first linked/quoted description is oddly incorrect. Specifically, IEnumerable is *Covariant*, not *Contra-variant*. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3221468) for reference.
I'd suggest calling this out to avoid more confusion.

Answer (score 3):

Note that since 2012, in .NET 4.5 and later, there exists a covariant (`out` modifier) interface,

```
public interface IReadOnlyList<out T>
```

see [its documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh192385.aspx).

Usual collection types like `List<YourClass>`, `Collection<YourClass>` and `YourClass[]` do implement `IReadOnlyList<YourClass>` and because of the covariance can also be used as `IReadOnlyList<SomeBaseClass>` and ultimately `IReadOnlyList<object>`.

As you have guessed, you will not be able to modify your list through a `IReadOnlyList<>` reference.

With this new interface, you might be able to avoid the non-generic `IList` all together. However you will still have the problem that `IReadOnlyList<T>` is not a base interface of `IList<T>`.

Comment: Actually, covariance and contravariance in generics are supported since .NET 4.0. Only the read-only interfaces like `IReadOnlyList<out T>` were added in .NET 4.5.

Answer (score 1):

Create an interface `MyIList<T>` and let it inherit from `IList<T>` and `IList`:

```
public interface MyIList<T> : IList<T>, IList
{ }
```

Now create a class `MySimpleList` and let it implement `MyIList<T>`:

```
public class MySimpleList<T> : MyIList<T>
{
    public int Count
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public bool IsFixedSize
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public bool IsSynchronized
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public object SyncRoot
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    object IList.this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        set
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        set
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public int Add(object value)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool Contains(T item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool Contains(object value)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void CopyTo(Array array, int index)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public int IndexOf(T item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public int IndexOf(object value)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Insert(int index, T item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Insert(int index, object value)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool Remove(T item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Remove(object value)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

What you can easily see now, is that you have to double implement a bunch of methods. One for the type T and one for object. In normal circumstances you want to avoid this. This is a problem of co-variance and contra-variance.

The best explanation you can find (for this concrete problem with IList and IList is the [article from Brad](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2005/01/18/355755.aspx) already mentioned by Jon within the comments of the question.

Comment: And many of the `IList` methods will need a `if(!(x is T)) throw ...` check. Makes implementing `IList` even more annoying.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Yes, that's one of the points that will encounter if you're going to implement this class.

Comment: @Oliver Actual problem is casting an `System.Collection.Generic.IList<T>` instance to a `System.Collection.IList` pointer. So writing another interface can't be a good solution of this problem.
To use this solution one have to use `MyIList<T>` and write individual wrappers for every concrete class which inherits `IList<T>` and `IList` like `class ListWrapper : List, MyIList {}` and constructors if necessary.
But It would be more easier if .NET `List<>` _(and other classes which actually inherit both `IList<>` and `IList`)_ inherits an interface like `MyIList`.

Comment: I don't want to say, you have should use your own interface. It simply illustrates, why IList<T> does not inherit from IList. If you try to do so on yourself (like in my example) then you'll see that you run into a lot of problems and that's the reason why Microsoft also didn't do so and leaved the interfaces separately.

Answer (score 0):

Good answers have already been given.
A notice about IList though:

[MSDN IList Remarks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist(v=vs.110).aspx):
"IList implementations fall into three categories: read-only, fixed-size, and variable-size. (...). For the generic version of this interface, see 
`System.Collections.Generic.IList<T>`."

This is a bit misleading because on the generic side, we have `IList<T>` as [variable-size](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb354714(v=vs.110).aspx), and `IReadOnlyList<T>` as read-only since 4.5 but AFAIK, there is no fixed-size generic List.