# Clarification on why IList<T> doesn't inherit from IList

Tags: c#, inheritance

The question about why `IList<T>` doesn't inherit from `IList` was asked before and answered.

The correct answer I believe was that if `IList<T>` did inherit from `IList`, then one could cast to IList and add items not of the correct type.

Here now comes my question.

Why does `List<T>` implement both `IList<T>` and `IList` then? If you cast `List<T>` to `IList` and add items not of type T you correctly get an exception.

So what's the purpose of `List<T>` implementing `IList`?

Comment: methinks for backward compatibility

Comment: "was asked before" -> link!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why generic IList<> does not inherit non-generic IList](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14559070/why-generic-ilist-does-not-inherit-non-generic-ilist)

Comment: @Ian: It's not quite a duplicate, as it does not highlight the fact that `List<T>` indeed *does* implement `IList`.

Comment: Because its a concrete implementation thats implemented in away to prevents doing something dump. How do you make sure that any IList<T> implementor does it when it would inherit from IList?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Ok - you said it was asked before, could you find another more relevant duplicate?

Comment: @Ralf: To be fair, you cannot make sure that `IList<T>` implementors do not do anything weird when implementing the interface as it is, either.

Comment: @Ian: I did not. The OP said that, I *cited* their statement, and *I* asked *them* for a reference to one of the questions that discussed the issue, but did not provide enough information for the specific aspect the OP is asking about.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Sorry, my mistake :)

Comment: @Ian: Granted, I "asked" in a very brief form. Sorry for the confusion ;)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper No worries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> then one could cast to IList and add items not of the correct type.

This is only a partial justification: It is well possible to implement `IList` in a way so no items of an incorrect type can be added - as evidenced by the implementation that is [`List<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

*However,*, `List<T>` already exists as a part of the base class library. For our convenience, it implements `IList` and throws exceptions. If we want to use its `IList` implementation, we can do so within these constraints, and if we do not want to use it, we have no further work.

In contrast to this, `IList<T>` is an interface. If it inherited from `IList`, every implementor of `IList<T>` would have to implement all of the weakly-typed methods of `IList`, adding a lot of work that is often not desired.

Moreover, note that `List<T>` implements `IList` *expilcitly*. That means, the public interface of `List<T>` does not grow; you only get the `IList` methods if you explicitly cast to `IList`. In an interface, that is not possible, as an interface cannot enforce explicit implementation of another interface.

Comment: Thank you for the in depth info. I can see the convenience of casting to an IList and using the methods in it that don't involve the specific type. However the code that may working against the IList interface may not know about the actual concrete implementation and assume all the methods would work. I completely agree with you explanation and I guess we should write code that prevents such a situation.