# Is returning IList<T> worse than returning T[] or List<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, interface, abstraction

The answers to questions like this: [List<T> or IList<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400135/c-sharp-listt-or-ilistt) always seem to agree that returning an interface is better than returning a concrete implementation of a collection. But I'm struggling with this. Instantiating an interface is impossible, so if your method is returning an interface, it's actually still returning a specific implementation. I was experimenting a bit with this by writing 2 small methods:

```
public static IList<int> ExposeArrayIList()
{
    return new[] { 1, 2, 3 };
}

public static IList<int> ExposeListIList()
{
    return new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
}
```

And use them in my test program:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IList<int> arrayIList = ExposeArrayIList();
    IList<int> listIList = ExposeListIList();

    //Will give a runtime error
    arrayIList.Add(10);
    //Runs perfectly
    listIList.Add(10);
}
```

In both cases when I try to add a new value, my compiler gives me no errors, but obviously the method which exposes my array as an `IList<T>` gives a runtime error when I try to add something to it. 
So people who don't know what's happening in my method, and have to add values to it, are forced to first copy my `IList` to a `List` to be able to add values without risking errors. Of course they can do a typecheck to see if they're dealing with a `List` or an `Array`, but if they don't do that, and they want to add items to the collection **they have no other choice to copy the `IList` to a `List`, even if it already is a `List`**. Should an array never be exposed as `IList`?

Another concern of mine is based upon the accepted answer of the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/400144/3410196) (emphasis mine):

> If you are exposing your class through a library that others will use, **you generally want to expose it via interfaces rather than concrete implementations.** This will help if you decide to change the implementation of your class later to use a different concrete class. In that case the users of your library won't need to update their code since the interface doesn't change.
>
> If you are just using it internally, you may not care so much, and using List may be ok.

Imagine someone actually used my `IList<T>` they got from my `ExposeListIlist()` method just like that to add/remove values. Everything works fine. But now like the answer suggests, because returning an interface is more flexible I return an array instead of a List (no problem on my side!), then they're in for a treat...

TLDR:

1) Exposing an interface causes unnecessary casts? Does that not matter?

2) Sometimes if users of the library don't use a cast, their code can break when you change your method, even though the method remains perfectly fine.

I am probably overthinking this, but I don't get the general consensus that returning an interface is to be preferred over returning an implementation.

Comment: Then return `IEnumerable<T>` and you have compile time safety. You can still use all LINQ extension methods which normally try to optimize performance by casting it to a specific type(Like `ICollection<T>` to use the `Count` property instead of enumerating it).

Comment: Still the same issue as point 1? If I return list as `IEnumerable<T>` they have to copy it to list, even though it's already a list. Isn't it bad to do unnecessary copy?

Comment: Arrays implement `IList<T>` by a "hack". If you want to expose a method returning it, return a type actually implementing it.

Comment: If your instance actually IS a list then casting gets trivial. However you may call `ToList` which may be cost-intensive when you do NOT have a List (but an array e.g.).

Comment: @HimBromBeere indeed, that's my point, it's already a list, but they have to copy it to another list just to be sure their code never breaks

Comment: @CodeCaster so the question in my title is correct? Implementation > `IList` in this case?

Comment: Just don't make promises you cannot keep.  The client programmer is pretty likely to be disappointed when he reads your "I'll return a list" contract.  It is not so just don't do that.

Comment: From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396): **IList is a descendant of the ICollection interface and is the base interface of all non-generic lists. IList implementations fall into three categories: read-only, fixed-size, and variable-size. A read-only IList cannot be modified. A fixed-size IList does not allow the addition or removal of elements, but it allows the modification of existing elements. A variable-size IList allows the addition, removal, and modification of elements.**

Comment: @AlexanderDerck: if you want that the consumer can add items to your list, don't make it `IEnumerable<T>` in the first place. Then it's fine to return `IList<T>` or `List<T>`.

Comment: From my point of view it depends: when I create a class I return the concrete type I'm working with. If I create an interface I try to be as general as possible and return an interface.

Comment: @dotctor Isn't it bad by microsoft for not creating 3 different interfaces then?

Comment: Your clients should never cast the objects they receive from your API. Any breakage caused by you changing the implementation is their problem. Technically `IList<T>` is not guaranteed to be modifiable, so the best you can probably do is add a post-condition that `Result<IList<int>>().IsReadOnly == false`.

Comment: @Lee I can live with that explanation, still seems wrong to me that users of an interface should do checks upon it to be able to use the interface correctly. I always learned interfaces should be a fixed contract, this is an odd case I suppose

Comment: @AlexanderDerck yes,I think it should be split into smaller interfaces. But you can check for `IList.IsFixedSize` and `IList.IsReadOnly`

Comment: *If you don't expect clients to need to know what actual type you're returning*, then return IList.

Comment: A side note: Exposing parts of the *state* of an object in a way that allows callers to modify the state (without the object itself noticing it) is often a bad idea. Returning a copy or an unmodifiable *view* allows a better control over the *state space* of the object.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Maybe this is not directly answering your question, but in .NET 4.5+, I prefer to follow these rules when designing public or protected APIs:

- do return `IEnumerable<T>`, if only enumeration is available;
- do return `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` if both enumeration and items count are available;
- do return `IReadOnlyList<T>`, if enumeration, items count and indexed access are available;
- do return `ICollection<T>` if enumeration, items count and modification are available;
- do return `IList<T>`, if enumeration, items count, indexed access and modification are available.

Last two options assume, that method must not return array as `IList<T>` implementation.

Comment: Not an answer indeed, but good rule of thumb and very helpful to me :) I've been struggling a lot with choosing what to return lately. Cheers!

Comment: This is indeed the right principle +1. Just for completeness I would add `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` and `ICollection<T>` which have their usage for non indexable containers (for instance the later is de facto a standard for EF entity sub collection navigation properties)

Comment: @IvanStoev Can you edit the answer please with those added? It would be nice if I finally get a list of where to use what interface

Comment: Unfortunately, `ICollection<T>` and `IList<T>` do not inherit from `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` nor `IReadOnlyList<T>`; class `List<T>` and `T[]` both do, however.  In some cases, that may be a fair argument for using one of the latter.

Comment: @supercat: that's true. Unfortunately, from architectural point collections in BCL are pain.

Comment: It has to be noted that `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` and `IReadOnlyList<T>` have the same flaw as the C++'s `const` does. There are two possibilities: either the collection is immutable, or it is only your way of access to the collection that forbids you from modifying it. And you cannot tell one from another.

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy: Actually, there are three possibilities.  The interface may guarantee that implementations may be safely exposed without giving the recipient the possibility of modifying the collection ("ReadOnly"), or may decline to provide a means of modifying the collection without promising that someone receiving a reference wouldn't be able to cast to a type that can modify it ("Readable").

Comment: When you mention certain features being available, are you talking about whether the concrete type supports them, or are you talking about whether the consumer is expected to need them?  For example, if the concrete type is `List<T>`, but you're only really building the list to gather a set of things to be enumerated on, are you recommending to return `IList<T>` to fully support what can be done with it, or are you recommending to return `IEnumerable<T>` because it'll cover what you're trying to expose and because it's easier to change implementations for?

Comment: @Panzercrisis: I would choose the second option, of course - `IEnumerable<T>`. As an API developer you have full knowledge about allowed use-cases. If method results are intended to be enumerated only, then there's no reason to expose `IList<T>`. The less allowed to do with result, the more flexible is the method implementation. E.g., exposing `IEnumerable<T>` allows you to change implementation to `yield return`s, `IList<T>` doesn't allow this.

Answer (score 31):

**No, because the consumer should know what exactly [IList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Anchor_4) is:**

> IList is a descendant of the ICollection interface and is the base
>   interface of all non-generic lists. IList implementations fall into
>   three categories: read-only, fixed-size, and variable-size. A
>   read-only IList cannot be modified. A fixed-size IList does not allow
>   the addition or removal of elements, but it allows the modification of
>   existing elements. A variable-size IList allows the addition, removal,
>   and modification of elements.

You can check for `IList.IsFixedSize` and `IList.IsReadOnly` and do what you want with it.

I think `IList` is an example of a fat interface and it should have been split into multiple smaller interfaces and it also violates [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) when you return an array as an `IList`.

[Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34334726/3970411) if you want to make decision about returning interface

---

**UPDATE**

Digging more and I found that `IList<T>` does not implement `IList` and   `IsReadOnly` is accessible through base interface [`ICollection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13(v=vs.110).aspx) but there is no `IsFixedSize` for `IList<T>`. Read more about [why generic IList<> does not inherit non-generic IList?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14559070/3970411)

Comment: Those properties are good, but it still defeats the purpose of an interface in my opinion. For me, interface is a contract, which shouldn't depend on any checks or whatever

Comment: It really would have been kinder to the developer if they'd provided an additional interface that has (non-fixed size/non-read-only) `List<T>` semantics, but there's probably sound reasoning as to why this wasn't included.... but, yes, I think your idea of several interfaces covering the various features would be a much sounder choice;

Comment: @AlexanderDerck Yes, that would be ideal. But that simply isn't the case here, so you have to live with what you have (the same thing applies for `Stream`, for example). You can always wrap the result in your own interface if you want to.

Comment: Jup, it would've been nicer but that's life I guess :D It's not a huge issue obviously but just something that's been bothering me and it makes it harder to understand the benefit of using interfaces to new programmers (like me)

Comment: `IList<T>` is a fat interface but it's the most you can get from array _and_ list. So if it would have broken into multiple interfaces you might not be able to use some methods with lists and arrays but only with one of them, even if all methods you want to use are supported(like `IList.Count` or the indexer). So in my opinion it was a good decision. If it causes a `NotSupportedException` in very few cases where one wants to use `Add` on an array, well, that's the deal.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Would it have had disadvantages if `IList` would've been implemented as `IList : IArray` ?

Comment: @TimSchmelter But it violiates L of SOLID!

Comment: @AlexanderDerck: it would add another interface `IArray`, what would be the advantage?

Comment: @TimSchmelter the features of array without the features of List? Or does array have some features that list doesn't have? I'm not sure

Comment: @dotctor What a coincidence, I was reading about Liskov substitution principle yesterday and that got me thinking actually :) thanks for the answer

Comment: @AlexanderDerck: so you mean that `IList` has `Add`(and so on) and `IArray` not? What is the difference? If you want to provide a method that works with lists and arrays you have to return (or accept as parameter) `IList` and the issue remains.

Comment: Well this answer combined with Dennis rules can certainly improve understanding of how to deal with this dilemma. Needless to say that Liskov substitution principle is violated here and there in .NET framework and it's not something particular to be worried about.

Comment: @TimSchmelter then i can return an interface and people know they can't add stuff to the collection which implements the interface. Now they just have to guess (+ it has benefit of random access compared to `IEnumerable`

Comment: @TimSchmelter: The collection interfaces unfortunately lack some important properties.  Any kind of `IEnumerable<T>`, for example, should be able to answer without difficulty questions like whether it's finite/infinite/unknown, whether its size is fixed/variable/unknown, whether it's mutable/immutable/read-only/unknown, etc.  Some implementations won't be able to do anything better than answer "unknown" for a lot of queries, but being able to ask the questions will allow callers to optimize for cases where they're using implementations that answer favorably.

Answer (score 13):

As with all "interface versus implementation" question, you'll have to realise what exposing a public member means: it defines the public API of this class.

If you expose a `List<T>` as a member (field, property, method, ...), you tell the consumer of that member: the type obtained by accessing this method *is* a `List<T>`, or something derived of that.

Now if you expose an interface, you hide the "implementation detail" of your class using a concrete type. Of course you can't instantiate `IList<T>`, but you can use an `Collection<T>`, `List<T>`, derivations thereof or your own type implementing `IList<T>`.

The *actual* question is *"Why does `Array` implement `IList<T>`"*, or *"Why has the `IList<T>` interface so many members"*.

It also depends on what you want the consumers of that member to do. If you actually return an internal member through your `Expose...` member, you'll want to return a `new List<T>(internalMember)` anyway, as otherwise the consumer can try and cast them to `IList<T>` and modify your internal member through that.

If you just expect consumers to iterate the results, expose `IEnumerable<T>` or `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` instead.

Comment: "The actual question is "Why does Array implement IList<T>", or "Why has the IList<T> interface so many members". ", that's indeed something I was struggling with.

Comment: @Fabjan - `IList<T>` does have methods to add and remove items, which is why it's bad for arrays to implement. The `IsReadOnly` property is a hack to gloss over the differences when it should have been split into (at least) two interfaces.

Comment: @Lee Whoops, you're right, deleting my inaccurate comment

Comment: @AlexanderDerck it's something I've asked previously http://stackoverflow.com/q/5968708/706456

Comment: @oleksii it's similar indeed, but I wouldn't call it a duplicate

Answer (score 8):

Be careful with blanket quotes that are taken out of context.

> Returning an interface is better than returning a concrete implementation

This quote only makes sense if it's used in the context of the [SOLID principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)). There are 5 principles but for the purposes of this discussion we'll just talk about the last 3.

### Dependency inversion principle

> one should “Depend upon Abstractions. Do not depend upon concretions.”

In my opinion, this principle is the most difficult to understand. But if you look at the quote carefully it looks a lot like your original quote.

> Depend on interfaces (abstractions). Do no depend on concrete implementations (concretions).

This is still a little confusing but if we start applying the other principles together it starts to make a lot more sense.

### Liskov substitution principle

> “objects in a program should be replaceable with instances of their subtypes without altering the correctness of that program.”

As you pointed out, returning an `Array` is clearly different behavior to returning a `List<T>` even though they both implement `IList<T>`. This is most certainly a violation of LSP.

The important thing to realize is that interfaces are about the **consumer**. If you're returning an interface, you've created a contract that any methods or properties on that interface can be used without changing the behavior of the program.

### Interface segregation principle

> “many client-specific interfaces are better than one general-purpose interface.”

If you're returning an interface, you should return the most client specific interface your implementation supports. In other words, if you're not expecting the client to call the `Add` method you shouldn't return an interface with an `Add` method on it.

Unfortunately, the interfaces in the .NET framework (particularly the early versions) are not always ideal client specific interfaces. Although as @Dennis pointed out in his answer, there are a lot more choices in .NET 4.5+.

Comment: Reading up on Liskov's principle was what got me confused in the first place for `IList<T>`

Comment: In the particular case it's the Array that violates LSP. If you are returning an IList you should never return an array because if this violation. You've already made the contract with the caller that they are getting back a list that can have items added and removed.

Answer (score 5):

Returning an interface is not necessarily better than returning a concrete implementation of a collection. You should always have a good reason to use an interface instead of a concrete type. In your example it seems pointless to do so.

Valid reasons to use an interface could be:

1. You do not know what the implementation of the methods returning the interface will look like and there may be many, developed over time. It may be other people writing them, from other companies. So you just want to agree on the bare necessities and leave it up to them how to implement the functionality.
2. You want to expose some common functionality independent from your class hierarchy in a type-safe way. Objects of different base types that should offer the same methods would implement your interface.

One could argue that 1 and 2 are basically the same reason. They are two different scenarios that ultimately lead to the same need.

"It's a contract". If the contract is with yourself and your application is closed in both functionality and time, there is often no point in using an interface.

Comment: I don't really agree, if it's possible to return an interface i'd return an interface as that's the only thing that's needed. If a method expects an interface, I can pass a class which only implements that interface to it, but also a class which implements the interface + loads of other things. With interface it's easier to extend your application without rewriting existing things

Comment: It can be _really_ enlightening to develop all your software (and especially your classes and class libraries) with the mindset of _"What if someone else was to use this class (library)?"_ and _"What if I want to add functionality to the concrete type I want to return?"_. BCL types can be sealed, so you can't extend them. Then you're stuck if you want to return something else, as your API promises to expose that exact type, as opposed to an interface. Returning an interface is almost always better than returning a concrete implementatoin.

Comment: I agree (really), I should have added a third reason: "limit the functionality of a returned object to its essence to clarify the message to the caller". I too return IReadOnlyXxx interfaces whenever possible rather than the full fledged object utilized to assemble the collection.