# Should I use IEnumerable as return type for an array?

Tags: c#

I have the following code to optimize execution time and only search for types once:

```
internal static Type[] SpecTestClasses =
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
            .SelectMany(t => t.GetTypes())
            .Where(t =>
                t.GetCustomAttribute<CompilerGeneratedAttribute>() == null &&
                t.GetCustomAttribute<TestClassAttribute>() != null &&
                t.GetCustomAttribute<SerialSeleniumTestAttribute>() != null)
            .ToArray();
```

I used to have:

```
internal static IEnumerable<Type> SpecTestClasses =
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
            .SelectMany(t => t.GetTypes())
            .Where(t =>
                t.GetCustomAttribute<CompilerGeneratedAttribute>() == null &&
                t.GetCustomAttribute<TestClassAttribute>() != null &&
                t.GetCustomAttribute<SerialSeleniumTestAttribute>() != null);
```

But that didn't optimize my execution since CurrentDomain was queried for each call. So I then added .ToArray(), and then changed the return type to Type[].

Now to my question: What return type should I have? Should I have kept the return type as IEnumerable and if so why? ReSharper didn't have any suggestions on the issue.

Thanks,
Drutten

**Edit:** For clarification, `GetAssemblies()` will not change during the applications lifetime.

Comment: Possibly, this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34334726/580053

Comment: I understand that the result of `GetAssemblies()`  would not change between calls? Then you should cache the result of the first call in a private container of *any* type you like and return an enumerable.

Comment: Having a public propety of array type will trigger this code analysis rule: [CA1819: Properties should not return arrays](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0fss9skc.aspx)

Comment: @MartinLiversage That is an interesting warning; I have never heard of it. Worries about the array integrity make sense in "hostile" environments when you don't know what callers of your properties may do, but for code under my own control I wouldn't take it too seriously.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider: Many code analysis warnings have been created by Microsoft for "library developers" , i.e. the Microsoft developers creating the .NET Base Class Library. In your own code you can completely ignore rules like that. But even in a small team you may discover that these rules are useful because there are no "hidden" rules that you get an array but you are not allowed to modify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's internal, I'd probably use `Type[]` because the many bad things that can happen if someone changes the array can be avoided by not changing the array.

If it was public, I'd wrap it in a `ReadOnlyCollection<Type>`. Then I'd have to decide on whether the convenience to the user of my exposing it as that, `IReadOnlyList<T>` or `IList<T>` outweighed the burden of my having to continue to support that from then on, while `IEnumerable<Type>` gives me more freedom to change implementation down the line.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider what makes you say that. Reading over the question, it seems the querent solved their performance problem with the `ToArray()` and were wondering solely about whether they were correct in changing the type the of the field it was stored in.

Answer (score 0):

It on depends on how you want to use **SpecTestClasses**. If you need just to enumerate it, I suggest to use **IEnumerable**. I think that you should cast to array only if you need to use indexes on your **SpecTestClasses**.

Comment: I thought that part of the problem is that each time the property is accessed, `CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()`  is executed again, which performs badly.

Answer (score 0):

It is always better to keep the data in the expression tree, so use the enumerable.
That way, always only one item will be retrieved from the expression tree's results. 
So If there is a possibility, that you'll not need all the items from the results, nor there is need to enumerate the results more than once, you should not convert it to array beforehand, as there is no gain in doing so.