# Issue with converting IEnumerable to List

Tags: c#, linq, generics, ienumerable, anonymous-types

I have a method **GetAllReportGroups** in which I was just returning an IEnumerable  but in a code review I was told NO, change it!

So now that I created more classes of which I "thought" this ReportGroupMaster would be the appropriate return type, I am getting 
this error.  I'm no longer using IEnumerable so it is confusing to me.

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<> items, int Id, int SortOrder, int Type>>' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a
>   cast?)

**Method**:

```
public List<ReportGroupMaster> GetAllReportGroups(string language)
    {

        List<ReportGroup> reportGroups = _envyUnitOfWork.ReportGroupsAll.GetAll().ToList();
        List<ReportDefinition> reportDefinition = _envyUnitOfWork.ReportDefinitions.GetAll().ToList();
        List<TraxReport> traxReports = _envyUnitOfWork.TraxReports.GetAll().ToList();

        List<ReportGroupItem> reportGroupItems = reportGroups.Select(reportGroup => new ReportGroupItem() {Id = reportGroup.Id, ReportGroupName = reportGroup.ReportGroupName, SortOrder = reportGroup.SortOrder, Type = (int) ReportTypeNames.ReportGroup}).ToList();

        //List<ReportGroupMaster> reportGroupItems = reportGroups.Select(reportGroup => new ReportGroupMaster() {Id = reportGroup.Id, ReportGroupName = reportGroup.ReportGroupName, SortOrder = reportGroup.SortOrder, Type = (int) ReportTypeNames.ReportGroup}).ToList();




       var query = from d in reportGroupItems
                    join r in reportDefinition on d.Id equals r.ReportGroupID into items
                    join cr in traxReports on d.Id equals cr.ReportGroupID into customItems
                    orderby d.SortOrder
                    select new
                    {
                        d.ReportGroupName,
                        items = items.Select(r => new
                        {
                            r.Id,
                            r.ReportGroupName,
                            r.SortOrder,
                            r.ReportGroupID,
                            r.Type// = (int) ReportTypeNames.ReportDefinition //r.Type
                        }).Concat(customItems.Select(cr => new
                        {
                            cr.Id,
                            cr.ReportGroupName,
                            cr.SortOrder,
                            cr.ReportGroupID,
                            cr.Type// = 4 //(int) ReportTypeNames.TraxReport    //cr.Type
                        })).OrderBy(e => e.SortOrder).ToList(),
                        d.Id,
                        d.SortOrder,
                        d.Type
                    };

        return query;

    }
```

Any thoughts?

**ReportGroupMaster**

```
public class ReportGroupMaster
{
    public string ReportGroupName { get; set; }
    public List<ReportGroupChild> Items { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }
}
```

**ReportGroupChild**

```
public class ReportGroupChild
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ReportGroupName { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
    public int ReportGroupID { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: " I was just returning an IEnumerable but in a code review I was told NO, change it" - why? Any explanation? Also, read this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34334363/is-returning-ilistt-worse-than-returning-t-or-listt/

Comment: Assuming your conversion is correct you are missing a `.ToList()`

Comment: Where do i put .ToList() ?

Comment: It is tied to an interface in which "they" said to not do  IEnumerable<object> GetAllReportGroups(string language);    because that is too hard for others to spot

Comment: How does your `ReportGroupMaster` looks like?

Comment: Let me add it to the question, hang on  - done  added it

Comment: You were returning an `IEnumerable<object>`? I can see why 'they' didn't like that. It's not the `IEnumerable` that's the problem, it's the `object` part: it doesn't give the caller any information on what a report is or what they can do with it. As for your problem, you're trying to return an enumerable of anonymous apples (`new { ... }`) while you're promising to return a list of oranges (`List<ReportGroupMaster>`).

Comment: @PieterWitvoet  -   Yep , i understand what you are saying.   and now the issue as well....   Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The `Linq` query in your case returns `IEnumerable<anonymoustype>` but the expected return type is `List<ReportGroupMaster>`, that's what is causing an error.

Use this code:

```cs
public List<ReportGroupMaster> GetAllReportGroups(string language)
{
    List<ReportGroup> reportGroups = _envyUnitOfWork.ReportGroupsAll.GetAll().ToList();
    List<ReportDefinition> reportDefinition = _envyUnitOfWork.ReportDefinitions.GetAll().ToList();
    List<TraxReport> traxReports = _envyUnitOfWork.TraxReports.GetAll().ToList();

    List<ReportGroupItem> reportGroupItems = reportGroups.Select(reportGroup => new ReportGroupItem() {Id = reportGroup.Id, ReportGroupName = reportGroup.ReportGroupName, SortOrder = reportGroup.SortOrder, Type = (int) ReportTypeNames.ReportGroup}).ToList();

    //List<ReportGroupMaster> reportGroupItems = reportGroups.Select(reportGroup => new ReportGroupMaster() {Id = reportGroup.Id, ReportGroupName = reportGroup.ReportGroupName, SortOrder = reportGroup.SortOrder, Type = (int) ReportTypeNames.ReportGroup}).ToList();

   var query = from d in reportGroupItems
                join r in reportDefinition on d.Id equals r.ReportGroupID into items
                join cr in traxReports on d.Id equals cr.ReportGroupID into customItems
                orderby d.SortOrder
                select new ReportGroupMaster()
                {
                    ReportGroupName  =d.ReportGroupName,
                    Items  = items.Select(r => new
                    {
                        r.Id,
                        r.ReportGroupName,
                        r.SortOrder,
                        r.ReportGroupID,
                        r.Type// = (int) ReportTypeNames.ReportDefinition //r.Type
                    }).Concat(customItems.Select(cr => new
                    {
                        cr.Id,
                        cr.ReportGroupName,
                        cr.SortOrder,
                        cr.ReportGroupID,
                        cr.Type// = 4 //(int) ReportTypeNames.TraxReport    //cr.Type
                    })).OrderBy(e => e.SortOrder).ToList(),
                    Id = d.Id,
                    SortOrder  = d.SortOrder,
                    Type = d.Type
                };

    return query.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous type: int Id, string ReportGroupName, int SortOrder, int ReportGroupID, int Type>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Envy.Business.Entities.Report.ReportGroupChild>' Envy.Business.Services C:\dev\Envy\Envy.Business.Services\Report\ReportService.cs 155 Active

Comment: Thoughts? on why the ReportGroupChild is causing the problem ( I can comment that "Items" part out and it works, but what is wrong with my Items ( ReportGroupChild)  ?

Comment: I did fix what I thought was the problem   public List<ReportGroupChild> Items { get; set; }   ,   but i still have the issue

Comment: I can actually put in   Items = new List<ReportGroupChild>(),   and then it builds,  but obviously that is not what I want...

Comment: Thanks,  I was hoping you were still around,  thanks again.  the OP did end up fixing my other problem to wrap the thing up ,  again thanks for a good start